# ANCOVA for allometric log-transformed growth data

Tags: data-transformation, ancova

I'm trying to perform an ANCOVA in R using weight and length data from a growth study in mollusks, in order to analyze changes in the allometric relationship W=aL^b over time in different treatment groups. For that, I'm log-transforming the data, as log(W)=log(a)+ b*log(L), and while log(w) data is normal, variances are not equal. I have tried log-transforming the data using different bases, including ln, so far with no luck. I wonder if anyone has any advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Variances of what are equal?

Comment: Why not try a power equation with a different form for error? See the paper by Lolli et al. in Proc. R. Soc. B for 2017.